# use coordinates in scatterplot to separate dataframe in R

Tags: r

Each point in this scatterplot is a column in a dataframe. I would like to get a list of columns to the left of the line I drew. I don't really know where to start with this now.
[image: scatterplot of the 1st 2 principal components]

To clarify my question, I want to get a list or array of columns to the left or right of that line. I don't need help drawing the line.

Here's how I generated the plot.

```
  pcaPlot = qplot(x=prin_comp$rotation[,1], y=prin_comp$rotation[,2]) +
                  geom_text(aes(label=row.names(prin_comp$rotation))) +
                  ggtitle(my_title)
```

Comment: Please help me rephrase my question too.. It's terrible. I'm pretty sure I could find an answer more easily if I knew how to ask it more elegantly.

Comment: Maybe read about "Cluster Analysis" ?

Comment: post the code that you used, you'd typically have the data for given point spanning a row of your dataframe (rather than a column as indicated). If you have the details of the line (y = ax + b) it's pretty straightforward to check if y < ax + b for a given row

Comment: Do you want the code that generated the plot? I drew that line in afterwards, to illustrate what I want. 
@zx8754, Cluster analysis is a huge subject...

Answer (score 1):

you can try a base R approach

```
# run a Principal Components Analysis
pca <- prcomp(USArrests)

# plot the first two components
plot(pca$x[,1], pca$x[,2])

# plot a straight line to a pPlot with slope == 0.5 
h <- abline(a = 0, b=0.5, lwd=2)
```

[image]

```
# hot wo calculate y=b*x
# use x*0.5 = y to find out if point lies left or right of the line
pca$x[,1]*0.5 < pca$x[,2]

# check with coloring
points(pca$x[,1], pca$x[,2], col=ifelse(pca$x[,1]*0.5 < pca$x[,2], 3, 2), pch=16)
```

[image]

Or using ggplot

```
library(tidyverse)
b <- 0.5
prcomp(USArrests) %>% 
  .$x %>% data.frame() %>% 
  mutate(gr=PC1*b<PC2) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(PC1, PC2)) + 
    geom_abline(slope = b, intercept = 0) +
    geom_point(aes(color=gr))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for help with the abline. But I have clarified my question now. I don't help plotting the different clusters, I want to separate (subset) the dataframe based on the clusters in the plot.

Comment: why not `cbind` the `PC1*b<PC2` to your data.frame? Just like `cbind(df, ifelse(PC1*b<PC2,"left","right"))`

Answer (score 1):

By eye, it looks as if your line is something like `y = -10x + 0.2875`, so you just need to test

```
(10*prin_comp$rotation[,1] + prin_comp$rotation[,2] - 0.2875) > 0
```

If this is `TRUE` then it is a point to the right of the line, if `FALSE` then it is to the left.